# Using bpy in a standalone python script dies when rendering

Tags: python, scripting, windows

## EDIT (Solution):

I was able to fix this by adding the following line:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
```

This works fine for me as I need to use the cycles engine anyways

## Original Post:

I'm writing a standalone python script to render .OBJ files automatically, without a .blend file or anything.  I installed bpy 2.82 on my windows machine using the instructions found [here](https://pypi.org/project/bpy/).  And I have python 3.7.9 installed.

Currently, as just a test to get my bearings, I tried the following code to try to setup a simple scene, load in a .OBJ, and render it out:

```
    import bpy
    import os
    from math import radians

    maplet_path = 'obj_files\\bunny.obj'
    image_out_path = 'render.png'

    # Create a Scene:
    scene       = bpy.data.scenes.new("Scene")
    camera_data = bpy.data.cameras.new("Camera")
    light_data  = bpy.data.lights.new(name="Light", type='SUN')

    # Import the maplet data:
    local_path = os.getcwd()
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=os.path.join(local_path,maplet_path))
    scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(local_path,image_out_path)
    scene.render.image_settings.file_format='PNG'

    # Get handles for all objects:
    maplet = bpy.context.selected_objects[0] 
    scene = bpy.data.scenes.new("Scene")
    camera = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", camera_data)
    sun    = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Light", object_data=light_data)

    # Setup camera parameters:
    scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
    scene.render.resolution_y = 1080
    camera.location = (-2.0, 3.0, 3.0)
    camera.rotation_euler = ([radians(a) for a in (422.0, 0.0, 149)])

    # Setup scene:
    sun.location = (2.0,2.0,2.0)
    sun.rotation_euler = (radians(10), radians(15), radians(20))
    maplet.location = (0,0,0)
    maplet.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)
        
    # Add camera to the scene:
    scene.camera = camera

    # Update the scene:
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()

    # Render:
    bpy.ops.render.render("EXEC_DEFAULT",write_still=True)
    bpy.data.images['Render Result'].save_render(os.path.join(local_path,image_out_path))
    print('hi')
```

Unfortunately, the program runs perfectly fine, but once it gets to the line:

```
bpy.ops.render.render("EXEC_DEFAULT",write_still=True)
```

it hangs for a moment, and then just exits.  It never prints 'hi', and it never writes any image.  It also doesn't print out any errors or anything else, it just stops running.

**I tried stepping through with pdb and it appears to hang/fail at:**

```
c:\......\python\python37\2.82\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py(182)idname_py()-'render.render'
-> return self._module + "." + self._func
```

Is there something wrong with how I went about installing bpy?  Or something wrong with the script I've written?

Comment: Can you start python 3.7.9  from terminal, and do a bare bones `import bpy` followed by `bpy.ops.render.render()` ?  Just checked (have bpy 2.90.2 built against python 3.8.2 (ubuntu)  and that simple test segfaults)

Comment: @batFINGER I just tried that, and you're right, it fails.  It doesn't give me any segfault errors, it just exits (so thats likely whats going on).  Which is weird...  because I have 100% used the my computers python37/bpy install to render from a .blend file (for some automation I needed before).  I'm not sure what could have changed...

Comment: @batFINGER I was able to fix this issue by adding: `bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'` to the script.  Which is a desireable fix for me anyways, since I want to be using cycles for this project anyways.  Unsure if that'll help those looking for eevee

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'
```

Fixed this issue